# How do I make an HTML5 Video player embeddable

Tags: html, video

YouTube allows people to embed their videos. How do I make this feature for my videos? Looking for guidance or a tutorial because I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube gives an iframe with src pointing to a page that contains only a video.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1PtR6qtdi1s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Do you see that src is equal to? http://www.youtube.com/embed/1PtR6qtdi1s

Got it?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can use the [video tag.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="src/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 VIDEO!
</video>
```

Change values to desired width, height, src and video type (it supports mp4, webm and ogg).